# create pages automatically and dynamically in wordPress

Tags: plugins, pages, database, authentication, table

Is there an easy way to create pages automatically and dynamically in wordPress? Let me explain further:
I am developing a website where I have more than 20 equal pages, with the same layout, where only 3 data fields change:
Image, description, how to do it.
Is there a way, for example, to enter the data in a table and wordpress create the page automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Yoast Duplicate Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/) instead of going for a complex solution.

Duplicate the page you have already created. Change Title, image, description and any other field you need. Save it and duplicate it to create the next page.

Comment: That would still need manual work: doing the copy. And as far as I understand it, OP is looking for a way to automate this.